# how to extract the ending from an email in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a list of emails and I want to extract / separate the endings (.com/.de/.co.uk) in Excel (so I can total the regions etc they come from).

Does someone know a simple way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (`A1` is your cell):

```
=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-SEARCH("#",SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","#",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",""))))+1)
```

Comment: Nitpick, but for `.co.uk` addresses, that will only return `.uk`.  Probably gets the user far enough, though

Comment: What if the address is `bob@bobsoffice.london.derpcompany.co.uk`?

Comment: yes, may not be 100%, but gets me far enough to take away a lot of pain!